Pulse DC reading
I'm trying to read current with INA186 on low-side. The shunt resistor calculations are ok, but the current sensed, comes from a pulse DC signal of a SCR. This SCR is rectifying the output of a power transformer, 220 VAC --> 10 VAC, that charges a lead-acid battery. So the voltage output of the INA186 it supposed to give a DC signal with a pulse component mounted on it. I'm reading this with ADC of uC, my trouble is when reading this signal, it's better to use a type of filter to obtain a pure DC? Or apply some software filtering? Because I want to measure average or rms value in my program. I know this may be a bit generalizing, but I think you understand my main problem.
(Mains frequency: 50 Hz).

What microcontroller is being used? There might be a reference design for the microcontroller for an electricity meter to give an idea of how to calculate the RMS current in software. E.g. the TI Implementation of a Single-Phase Electronic Watt-Hour
Meter Using the MSP430F6736(A) shows a 24-bit ADC sampling current at 4096 Hz and integrating samples over one second to calculate the RMS current.

The uC used is PIC16F18076 . It has some computation modes, but I can´t make it work with that.
